# Need feedback for a PCB design (digital/analog synth)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, noise, ground-plane

Ok so I'm designing a synth using the NES sound chip (AY-3-8910). After poorly designing a PCB for it and testing it, I realized there is noise from the MIDI input bleeding to the audio output.

I read a lot since then and trying to do a somewhat acceptable design this time.

So, different parts of the circuit:
A: Power supply input
B: Analog audio part (EQ and output amp)
C: MIDI input and output (VERY NOISY section!!!)
D: AY-3-89-10. The IC that receives bus data from "1" beneath it and generate audio output to B.
E: Microcontroller (atmega328), buttons, leds, pots, everything digital.

I took a "separate grounds" approach, and I bridged together the ground when there was signals going from one section to another, as you can see in "1", "2" and "3".

One of my concerns is the two traces marked as "2", those are the MIDI input and output signals and are very noisy, I mean they irradiate interference.

The arrows are pointing the power traces directions, all coming from the power section.
There are a lot of connections missing, but wanted to sort this out first.

What do you think??Thanks for your time!!!! :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: AY-3-8910 is not a NES sound chip, but MSX. Please post schematics as it is needed to understand PCB.

Comment: you probably want to filter the power between A and D and definately between A and B, could maybe use two regulators one for digital and one for analogue

Comment: @Justme ups, you are right, my whole life it's a lie, oh well it sounds alike.
I uploaded it the schematic!

Comment: @Jasen you mean with a ferrite? or with a resistor and cap on power trace?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Comment: look at the designs used by respected musical instrument makers like Korg and Roland, you will find schematics and board images on the internet.

Comment: They don't sound alike at all. However, the ground slots do not isolate current paths well, it forms loops - it is difficult to get right. Also the supply wires are long and small, so they are quite inductive and adding some larger bulk caps could help, maybe ferrites to isolate noisy circuits. One big thing is that the optoisolator is most likely the chip with fastest and largest transients on this board, and it lacks a bypass cap and it could have a 100R in series on data line to limit transients from happening.

Comment: If that is the real PCB you are using, the optoisolator output is shorted to 5V supply at resistor R21, which would explain the noise when receiving MIDI.

Comment: @Justme the power trace width is calculated for more than x4 the current that goes through it, I dont know if that changes things, just saying. About larger caps you mean more than the 220uF I used? Or more of them? Also ferrite goes through sensitive ICs? Or through noisy ICs? Are you saying I would be better by just joining ground all together in one single piece?? R21 is not going to VCC, sorry the schematic is confusing, its just goign to RX on the Atmega328, also I think a 100R would make the signal to become unreadable by the microcontroller

Comment: The short is on the PCB, not in the schematics. The red RX and VCC traces overlap at resistor R21. And the 100R in series would not make the signal unreadable by MCU, it is for source termination, look the word up if you don't believe me. And while narrow traces are 4x wider than needed DC current, the digital logic does not pull current at DC, it pulls spikes of operating current during transitions, like the AVR running at its clock frequency, so narrow traces have higher inductance and not good for AC currents. But that and adding caps may now be irrelevant if you simply have a short.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about R21 overlapping VCC, I moved it and forgot to move signal, but it's not the real PCB, it's just my next design.
I looked up "source termination" but couldn't find anything related to MIDI protocol, I'm using standard MIDI circuit, as seen here: https://mutable-instruments.net/archive/schematics/Shruthi-Digital-v08.pdf
This is a very respectable synth, the Shruthi.
Also this synth has only one ground pour, but it has separate digital and analog PCBs and the ground gets together only at one point

Comment: Also, will do thicker power traces.